# Connect sparklyr to remote spark connection

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I would like to connect my local desktop RStudio session to a remote spark session via sparklyr. When you go to add a new connection in the sparklyr ui tab in RStudio and choose cluster is says that you have to be running on the cluster, or have a high bandwidth connection to the cluster.

Can anyone shed light on how to create that kind of connection? I am not sure how to create reproducible example of this, but in general what I would like to do is:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://ip-[MY_PRIVATE_IP]:7077", spark_home = "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.0.0", version="2.0.0")
```

from a remote server. I understand that there will be latency, especially if trying to pass data between the remotes. I also understand that it would be better to have the rstudio-server on the actual cluster- but that is not always possible, and I am looking for a sparklyr option for interacting between my server and my desktop RStudio session. Thanks.

Comment: Is it throwing an error when you try to use spark_connect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [sparklyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparklyr/index.html) version `0.4`, it is unsupported to connect from the RStudio desktop to a remote Spark cluster. Instead, as you mention, the recommended approach is to install RStudio Server within the Spark cluster.

That said, the [livy branch](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/tree/feature/livy) in sparklyr is exploring integration with Livy that would enable the RStudio desktop to connect to a remote Spark cluster through Livy.

Answer (score 8):

Using more recent version of sparklyr (version `0.9.2` for example) it's possible to connect to a remote Spark cluster.

Here is an example to connect to a Spark **standalone** cluster version `2.3.1`.
See [Master URLs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) for other master URL schemes.

```
#install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)

# You have to install locally (on the driver where RStudio is running) the same Spark version
spark_v <- "2.3.1"
cat("Installing Spark in the directory:", spark_install_dir())
spark_install(version = spark_v)

sc <- spark_connect(spark_home = spark_install_find(version=spark_v)$sparkVersionDir, 
                    master = "spark://ip-[MY_PRIVATE_IP]:7077")

sc$master
# "spark://ip-[MY_PRIVATE_IP]:7077"
```

*I've written a [post](https://www.back2code.me/2018/11/configure-sparklyr-to-connect-to-a-standalone-spark-cluster/) on this topic.*

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to connect my local R to a cloud instance of Spark cluster (HD insights in my case) using [Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/)

within sparklyr's spark_connect there is an option to connect to livy. (Method = "**livy**")

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "https://<clustername>.azurehdinsight.net/livy/",
                     method = "livy", config = livy_config(
                       username = "<admin>",
                       password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Livy password:")))
```